# Flask - How can I pass a number on as part of a form without printing it as part of the html?

Tags: python, forms, flask

This is the code for the form class and page:

```py
@bp.route('/questions/<int:page>', methods=('GET',))
def questions(page):
    class Assessment(FlaskForm):
        back = SubmitField("back")
        next = SubmitField("next")
        save = SubmitField("save")
        submit = SubmitField("submit")

        pageNumber = page

        # some RadioFields here

    question_form = Assessment()
    return render_template('questions.html', questions=question_form)
```

This is the html jinja code:

```html
      {% if questions.pageNumber > 1 %}
        {{ questions.back }}
      {% endif %}
      {% if 9 > questions.pageNumber %}
        {{ questions.next }}
      {% endif %}
```

That code is meant to stop the back button from being created if it's on page 1, and the next button from being created if it's on page 9 (the last page).

The problem arises here:

```py
@bp.route('/submit', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def submit():

    form = request.form
    page = form["pageNumber"]
    del form["pageNumber"]

    # some unrelated code
    
    if "back" in form:
        return redirect(url_for('website.questions', page=page - 1))
    elif "next" in form:
        return redirect(url_for('website.questions', page=page + 1))
    elif "save" in request.form:
        return redirect(url_for('website.questions', page=page))
```

As you can see the idea is that the page number is passed, some code happens, and then the user is redirected to a page depending on what button they pressed.

The problem is in the line

> page = form["pageNumber"]

The error is

> werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
> KeyError: 'pageNumber'

It appears that since the user doesn't assign a value to pageNumber, it's not passed on with the form. However this is obviously problematic since I need the pageNumber to determine which page of questions they should be sent to next.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: the form:

```html
<form method="post" action="/submit">
      {% for question in questions %}
        {% if question.type == "RadioField" %}
          {{ question.label }}
          <br>
          {% for subfield in question %}
            <tr>
              <td>{{ subfield }}</td>
              <td>{{ subfield.label }}</td>
            </tr>
          {% endfor %}
          {% if not loop.last %}
            <br><br>
          {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      
      {% if questions.pageNumber > 1 %}
        {{ questions.back }}
      {% endif %}
      {% if 9 > questions.pageNumber %}
        {{ questions.next }}
      {% endif %}
      {{ questions.save }}
      {{ questions.submit }}
```

Edit: I found a solution. I changed the action for the form to

> action="{{ url_for("website.submit", page = questions.pageNumber) }}

Comment: You need to post your form that you pushed. I think you missed pushing pageNumber correctly

Comment: @Muhtar just added it in an edit. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are getting your questions from a DB. If it's `flask-sqlalchemy` then you should consider using the `Pagination` function which eliminates much of your code. [Here is a good example.](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-ix-pagination)

Comment: I'm currently using sqlite for my database, with plans to switch to a better database when I publish the website. The pagination feature definitely looks useful, although I don't think it replaces much of my code (currently I have a column for page number in the questions table, so when I query I just grab all the questions with the page number the user is on). Also not all of my pages will have the same number of questions (some might have 5, others 11, others 17, etc). 

I might be totally wrong about it being able to replace much of my code though, I'm an inexperienced coder.

Comment: I still think you should consider pagination. Since you have different questions for different pages, all you have to do is when you call the next_page route, set the "limit" attribute to the number of questions in that page. All am saying is that you are manually implementing what the Pagination class already offers.